# OpenCV error on Raspbian: Corrupt jpeg data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have written this code to take pictures with a webcam. While I run it on a raspberry pi it gives me this error : Corrupt jpeg data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6
How can I solve this problem?

```
 i=0
 cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while(True):
            ret,img=cam.read();
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces=faceDetec.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,10)
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                i+=1
                #il faut que le fichier dataSet existe déjà...
                # on enregistre l'image dans le fichier dataSet sous le nom User.id.i.jpg
                #gray[y:y+h,x:x+w] est l'image croppée on ne sauve que le visage.
                cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+str(id)+"."+str(i)+".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
                # on attend 500 milli secondes pour pouvoir changer de tête grimace, profil, avec lunettes,...
                cv2.waitKey(1000)
                cv2.waitKey()
            cv2.imshow("Face",img);
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            if i>=20:
                break
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        os.system("pause")
```

Comment: This is a common problem with webcams and Raspberry Pi: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47586&p=372981.  The suggestion is to manually update the kernel.  Also, some users have reported that even with those errors, the image data can still be viewed.  Have you tried opening the images?

Comment: The error occur here {ret,img=cam.read();}

Comment: Yes I can open the images but the process slows down.

Comment: Ok but how can I Hide those warnings?

Comment: I would not attribute the slowing down to that corrupt JPEG data error.  Remember that you are also writing images to your SD card which of course your RPi is running off of so that may attribute to it slowing down.  Is the SD card very fast in read/write time?  [Not all SD cards are created equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speeds).  Also remember that read/write performance of your SD card is a factor in the operation of your RPi.

Comment: The speed of my sd is 30Mb/s

Comment: You can redirect the output to `/dev/null` so that you don't see anything written to the terminal: `python yourprogram.py > /dev/null 2>&1`, where `yourprogram.py` is the source file of your webcam image capturing program.

Answer (score 0):

My program continously acquires images and continously prints out these error messages, so you don't see the relevant messages among this garbage. My solution: instead of calling

```
./myprogram
```

I call

```
unbuffer ./myprogram |& grep --line-buffered -v "Corrupt JPEG data:"
```

The grep command suppresses the unwanted messages. "|&" is a pipe which unites stdout and stderr, and "unbuffer" and "--line buffer" prevent from buffering. Without that, I see the output on the terminal only after termination of "myprogram". Program "unbuffer" is part of the package "expect".
This works on my PC with Linux Mint, and should work on Raspbian as well.